# Android - Text box background styling

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

I'm trying to achieve a text box styling similar to the image below. 
[image]

I tried creating a text view dynamically and I achieved something like this. Can someone help me achieve the styling similar to above image?

[image]

Below is the code block I used to achieve the above style.

chat_bubble.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#D8000000" />
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="1dp" android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

Activity.kt

```
fun createTextView(activity: PlacesActivity){
    var textView = TextView(this)
        textView.setText("Text ABCDD")
        textView.textSize = 24F
        textView.alpha = 0F
        textView.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA)

        textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chat_bubble)
        textView.setPadding(10,10,10,10)
        var params =
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(50,50,50,50)

        textView.setLayoutParams(params)
        linearLayout.addView(textView, params);

        fadeMarker(textView)

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Create a shape for your chat bubble background:

shape_pill_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="40dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="40dp"
        android:radius="40dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="40dp"
        android:topRightRadius="40dp" />
    <solid android:color="#555555" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />

    <size android:height="40dp" />
</shape>
```

create your arrow drawable:

shape_arrow_down.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="230%"
            android:pivotY="30%"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#555555" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

find an asset that best represents your "gold" arrow, i took the in built android studio vector asset which will be referred to as ic_arrow_forward_wattle_24dp.xml. Create your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutTextBubble"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_pill_background"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewInput"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="#919191"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="This is a text message"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageViewArrow"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewArrow"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewInput"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewInput"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textViewInput"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_wattle_24dp" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewDownArrow"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_arrow_down"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/constraintLayoutTextBubble"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/constraintLayoutTextBubble"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayoutTextBubble" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The result will look like this:

[image]

There is a few problems with this however. When you have a fairly large message it will push the arrow ImageView out of the bubble because of how wrap_content works in chains and constraint layout. I suggest you try giving your message TextView a fixed width or set its width to match constraints. This will give your text the grey background where there is no text. Play around with it and see what works best for you.

Comment: Thanks bko. But I'm trying to create all these dynamically. (because based on the json output the number of text views on a scrollable layout might change.)
So i'm afraid it is not as easy as using a layout file. But yeah thanks once again for the code. I will try to use this and try to create them dynamically